# Sorting after data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am working on a list of divs that contain custom data-attributes that I want to sort with a selection. If selected for example 'followers' it will be sorted after the .box's data-followers.

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nbgo117b/

I was thinking something like this, but I can't make it work.

```
 $("#sorter").change(function() {
    var value = $("#sorter option:selected").val();
    var boxOrdered;

    if (value == 'date' ){
        boxOrdered = $('.influencer .box').sort(function(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('followers')) < ($(a).data('followers')) ? 1 : -1;
    });
  }
$(".influencer").html(boxOrdered);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$.sort` to compare the data attribute just like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var $influencer = $('.influencer');
       $("#sorter").on('change',function() {
         var criterion = $(this).val();
         $influencer.find('.box').sort(function (a, b) {
           var valA = $(a).find('[data-'+criterion+']').data(criterion);
           var valB = $(b).find('[data-'+criterion+']').data(criterion);
           return (valA < valB) ? 1 : (valA > valB) ? -1 : 0;
         }).appendTo($influencer);
       });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<selection id="sort">
<select id="sorter">
<option value="default">Sort by</option>
<option value="followers">Most followers</option>
<option value="likes">Most likes</option>
<option value="views">Most views</option>
<option value="date">Newsest</option>
<option value="alpha">Alphabetical order</option>
</select>
</selection>   

 <div class="influencer">
    <div class="box" data-added="20.20.2018">
      <span class="followers" data-followers="1500000">1.5M followers</span>
      <span class="likes" data-likes="200000">200K likes</span>
      <span class="views" data-views="100000">100K video views</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box" data-added="20.20.2018">
      <span class="followers" data-followers="2500000">2.5M followers</span>
      <span class="likes" data-likes="80000">80K likes</span>
      <span class="views" data-views="200000">200K video views</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated my JsFiddle, but doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/nbgo117b/2/

Comment: you missed jquery in you fiddle, I've edited my answer adding html and jquery, so it can be run inside stackoverflow ;) And I've reverted the sort order so, the div with higher results will be up :)

Comment: Ops! My bad haha. Thank you very much. Works well. Do you know how I can also make it so it works for the data-added and sort after newest date?

Comment: replace the selection of value with something like `var valA = (criterion === 'date' ? $(a) : $(a).find('[data-'+criterion+']')).data(criterion);` and the same for `valB`, obviously. In this way if you are looking for date it will pick the data attribute from the element itself, otherwise it will search for something with `[data-xxx]` inside the element :)

Comment: P.s. this method will work if you use a timestamp or a date similar to `YYYYMMDD`, otherwise you also have to parse the date so that you can compare it ;)